# Has anyone had issues when trying to download the "CE_ARDUINO_LIB" from Github?

Tags: arduino-ide

Hello all: I am very new to all of this and suspect that I am doing something wrong. I try to download the library using the IDE (Version 1.8.15) and get the error messageArduino: 1.8.15 (Windows Store 1.8.49.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Error downloading https://downloads.arduino.cc/packages/package_index.json

Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library

Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library

I am trying to use a 4-20mA current loop board from NCD.io and this is the library that they say to use.

Thank you for your time

Comment: The file is the standard Arduino boards management package file that to be setup via Arduino -> Preferences, and you probably already have it under "Additional Boards Manager URLs". To download an Arduino Library from IDE, go to "Tools" -> "Manage Library..." to search for the library you want to download.

Comment: I have searched the Arduino Library Manager several times but the "CE_ARDUINO_LIB" is not on it. I can find it on Github but for some reason when I download it and try to add zip file from the IDE that is when the error message appears.

Comment: Sometime the library does not have the proper setup of `library.properties` file  or registered with the Arduino library that  Arduino Library Manager used to find the library. Just down the library from the github and add it to the library directory(if not available, create one) inside your Arduino/ directory, or use `git clone <the_library>.git` to download it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will give it a try and let you know